# Why vertex transformation outside GPU is not the same vertex transformation inside GPU?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, shader

As we know if we want to draw something in World space we need multiply our data by view and projection matrices. Now I need for my task to make vertex transformation outside shaders and sent transformated vertex directly. Like this:

**Initialization matrix**

```
glm::mat4 view, projection;
view = glm::lookAt(this->cameraPos, this->cameraPivot, this->Up);
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

**Code**

```
vector<glm::vec3> data;
glm::mat4 projection, view;
...
data.push_back(glm::vec3(projection * view * glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)));
data.push_back(glm::vec3(projection * view * glm::vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0)));
data.push_back(glm::vec3(projection * view * glm::vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0)));
data.push_back(glm::vec3(projection * view * glm::vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)));
...
shader.set();
GLuint VAO,VBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &wVBO);
glBindVertexArray(wVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, wVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(vector<glm::vec3>), &data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
...
glBindVertexArray(wVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, data.size());
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**Shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

But I get wrong view transformation - it looks like my data doesn't take into account the projection matrix, only the view matrix. But if I change it as usual:

**Code**

```
 ...
 data.push_back(glm::vec3(glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)));
 ...
 shader.set();
 glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "matrices"), 1,
 GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection * view));
```

**Shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 matrices;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = matrices * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

it's works as expected. What is my mistake? In my task needs to know position all of vertex in World-space before it will sended in shader. How can I do that?

Comment: Kinda hard to compare, when we don't know your vertex shader.

Comment: Ok, one minute!

Comment: also please show the code where you initialise view and projection matrices

Comment: Ok, two minutes!)

Comment: Ok, done.......

Comment: glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)) should be glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0)) the w coord should be 1 for all verts or else no transform will happen

Comment: also "think sizeof(vector<glm::vec3>)" should be  "sizeof(glm::vec3)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The homogeneous coorinate "w" for your vertices should be 1.0f or else no transform will be applied to the vertex.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Thanks Daniel for idea!!!
In my case no matters "w" is in inicialization of vertices. This is important in another.
Looks on a shader code in example #2:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in --->vec3<--- position;

uniform mat4 matrices;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = matrices * vec4(position, --->1.0f<---);
}
```

In input shader I send vec3 and it's wrong! We need to save "w" component which produced from matrix multiplication:

**Shader**

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
...
void main()
{
    gl_Position = matrices * position;
}
```

**Code**

```
vector<glm::vec4> data;
glm::mat4 projection, view;
...
data.push_back(projection * view * glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0));
...
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), &data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
....
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

That's it! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

glm::vec4 as bytes is smth + 4 floats  when shader expects 4 floats. At least size is wrong(and I suspect data too).That's said about all : question ,answer and comments.